# Error "Node 136 (UndefinedKeyword) was unexpected" after upgrading from 2.0.10 to 2.1.1

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

After upgrading from 2.0.10 to 2.1.1 I'm getting the following error. I've no idea which one of my source files is causing the trouble. Any hint is appreciated.

```
[10:30:50] Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Unexpected node.
Verbose Debug Information: Node 136 (UndefinedKeyword) was unexpected.
    at Object.assert (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:3001:23)
    at Object.Debug.failBadSyntaxKind (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42746:55)
    at serializeTypeNode (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44666:30)
    at serializeTypeNode (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44637:56)
    at serializeReturnTypeOfNode (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44563:24)
    at addOldTypeMetadata (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44428:136)
    at addTypeMetadata (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44416:17)
    at transformAllDecoratorsOfDeclaration (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44241:13)
    at generateClassElementDecorationExpression (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44288:40)
    at generateClassElementDecorationExpressions (C:\workspace\software-engineering\mean-ohne-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44268:34)
[10:30:50] 'ts' errored after 4.37 s
```

Comment: Maybe could you [submit your issue to the TS team](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues)?

Comment: OK, here it is: https://github.com/Microsoft/Typescript/issues/12464

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `tsconfig.json` where I was having these 2 lines:

`"inlineSources": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,`